# I want to use recursion to get the names of all the files in a directory structure

Tags: perl

I know that there are easier ways to do this, but I need to make some manipulations to the files when I find them so this is the way I want to do it.

I am using Strawberry Perl for Windows.

```
my $baseDir = 'U:\\bin\\';
my $logFile = 'C:\\bintmp\\replace.log';

open(LOG,'>',$logFile);

folder($baseDir);

sub folder {
  my $input = shift; # May be a file or dir

  my @fileList = <$input*>;

  foreach my $file (@fileList) {
    if (-f ($file)) {   
      print LOG basename($file) . "\n";
      next;
    }

    if (-d ($file)) {
      folder($file); # Recursively call the folder function
    }
  }
  return 1;
}
close(LOG);
```

I think I know what is happening. As I drill down into new folders The `@fileList` is being replaced so that it just sits at the bottom dir. This code will run forever.

Comment: Why does [`File::Find`](https://metacpan.org/module/File::Find) not do what you want? That module allows you to manipulate the files you find.

Comment: Ya, I could but now I just want to know why this isn't working. I haven't worked with many recursive perl function and would like to get better with them.

Comment: `return 1` -- what is that for?

Comment: You'll easily figure why this isn't working once to try to *read* what you've posted.

Comment: @devnull do you think comments like this are helpful? I'm really not sure what point you're trying to get across. Looking at some of your other comments you just look like a stackoverflow troll! please go away.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that you have no backslash before the `*` in your `glob`, so you are searching `U:\bin\XX` and then `U:\bin\XX*` which includes the same directory.

Note also that you should *always* `use strict` and `use warnings`; lower-case and underscore identifiers are a de-facto standard for Perl local variables; and you should *always* check that your `open` calls succeed.

There is no need to use multiple backslashes in single-quoted strings, unless it is at the end of the string or there is more than one of them together.

Try this instead

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use File::Basename 'basename';

my $base_dir = 'U:\bin';
my $log_file = 'C:\bintmp\replace.log';

open(my $log, '>', $log_file) or die $!;

folder($base_dir);

sub folder {

  my ($input) = @_;

  my @file_list = glob "$input\\*";

  foreach my $file (@file_list) {
    if (-f $file) {   
      print $log basename($file), "\n";
    }
    elsif (-d $file) {
      folder($file);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: It should perhaps be noted that this can be solved (better) with less code using File::Find. For example `perl -MFile::Find -lwe"find(sub { -f && print },'.');" > c:/bintmp/replace.log`

Comment: @TLP: Already noted in the comments on the question. Plus you need `basename`.

Comment: Why would I need basename? `$_` is already the basename of the file inside the wanted subroutine.